# Wait for file to appear and disappear?

Tags: python, ruby, file

I am downloading a file using chromedriver. it creates a 'crcdownload' file and then turns it into a file.

I did this in ruby using the following code. but not sure how I can make the `wait_for_download` equivalent in Python. Another added requirement is that if the download takes longer than 30 seconds, or if the crcdownload doesn't disappear within that time period, it should quit.

```
  def wait_for_download
    Timeout.timeout(TIMEOUT) do
      sleep 0.1 until downloaded?
    end
  end

  def downloading?
    downloads.grep(/\.crdownload$/).any?
  end

 def downloaded?
    !downloading? && downloads.any?
  end
```

What python module is best used for this scenario? to monitor a directory and then be updated when a certain event happens with a timeout so that it doesn't block indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of doing a sleep works, although there's a better way that's more efficient.

The better way is to use file system monitoring capabilities:

- [Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) on Linux
- [FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) on OSX
- [Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows

Ruby and Python both have tools that work cross-platform, and use the native file system's monitoring and notification, and are non-blocking.

- One such Ruby gem is [Listen](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/listen)
- One such Python package is [Watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)